# Deploy Azure App Service with multiple Virtual Applications using Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, azure-web-app-service, web-deployment

I currently am using Azure Cloud Service (classic) and am able to effectively deploy a WebApp that contains 4 virtual applications using an Azure Cloud Service project. My ServiceDefinition.csdef file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceDefinition name="My.Azure.Web.API" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition" schemaVersion="2015-04.2.6">
  <WebRole name="My.Web.API" vmsize="Small">
    <Sites>
      <Site name="Web" physicalDirectory="{path to My.Web.API}">
        <VirtualApplication name="webapp1" physicalDirectory="{path to My.Web.WebApp1}" />
        <VirtualApplication name="webapp2" physicalDirectory="{path to My.Web.WebApp2}" />
        <VirtualApplication name="webapp3" physicalDirectory="{path to My.Web.WebApp3}" />
        <VirtualApplication name="webapp4" physicalDirectory="{path to My.Web.WebApp4}" />
        <Bindings>
          <Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="Endpoint1" />
          <Binding name="HttpsIn" endpointName="HttpsIn" />
        </Bindings>
      </Site>
    </Sites>
    <Endpoints>
      <InputEndpoint name="Endpoint1" protocol="http" port="80" />
      <InputEndpoint name="HttpsIn" protocol="https" port="443" certificate="{certname}" />
    </Endpoints>
    <Imports>
      <!--<Import moduleName="Diagnostics" />-->
      <Import moduleName="RemoteAccess" />
      <Import moduleName="RemoteForwarder" />
    </Imports>
    <ConfigurationSettings>
      
    </ConfigurationSettings>
    <Certificates>
      <Certificate name="{certname}" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" />
    </Certificates>
  </WebRole>
</ServiceDefinition>
```

I am working on migrating to Azure App Service and despite some significant digging I can not seem to find an equivalent/similar deployment process in Visual Studio for multiple Virtual Applications in Azure App Service.

I have found numerous posting that indicate using the publish function in the actual WebApp projects, but I would have to perform 4 separate deployments instead on one. And need to pre-define the virtual directories in the App Service configuration. Under the current approach, virtual applications/directories are defined during the deployment.

I plan to eventually move to Azure DevOps Pipelines for CI/CD and hope there is a  mechanism to achieve this, but for now would just like something functional from Visual Studio.

Is there an equivalent/similar deployment process in Visual Studio for multiple Virtual Applications in Azure App Service? If not, what are the options?

Apologies if this a re-tread. I did my due diligence with no definitive answers. Unless of course the answer is right in front of me!?
Thanks for your time!

Eric

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check the below steps to deploy multiple Virtual Applications to Azure App Service from Visual Studio 2022.

- Create a new App Service in Azure Portal.

[image]

- In App Service Overview, click on the `Download publish profile`.

[image]

- In `VS 2022`, create Applications of your desired framework. I have taken `.NET Core Apps` as an example.

***Visual Studio Project Folder Structure***

[image]

The option to create `Virtual Directories` in Azure Portal is available only for `Azure Windows App Service`.

- In `Azure Portal` => `App Service` => `Configuration`  => `Path mappings` => Under `Virtual applications and directories` create `New Virtual application`.

[image]

- Make sure the `Virtual Path` is same as `Web App Name` in `VisualStudio`.

***Publish each Application in VS to Azure App Service using the Downloaded Publish Profile.***

- Right click on the `1st WebApp` Project => `Publish` => Add a publish profile => `Import Profile`.

[image]

- Browse and upload the `Publish Profile` which we have downloaded from `Azure Portal App Service`.

[image]

- Change the settings of the Application.
- The site name must be the `App Service name/VirtualPathName` which we have created in portal.
  ***Ex:*** Here it is `VirtualApps29Dec/WebApp1`.

[image]

- Save and continue with next steps to publish the App.
- Follow the same steps with the same `Publish Profile` for `WebApp2`, `WebApp3` and `WebApp4` as well.

***Deployed Azure App Service Structure in KUDU Console***

[image]

The `Url's` for the Applications will be

```cs
https://virtualapps29dec.azurewebsites.net/WebApp1
https://virtualapps29dec.azurewebsites.net/WebApp2
https://virtualapps29dec.azurewebsites.net/WebApp3
https://virtualapps29dec.azurewebsites.net/WebApp4
```

Initially When I tried to access the Applications, I got the below error.

[image]

When I check the `Web.config` of the deployed Applications, I can see the below code.

```cs
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\WebApp2.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile="\\?\%home%\LogFiles\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: c238430b-40de-45d7-bbb7-ad96da7c4dc4-->
```

- `AspNetCoreModuleV2` will not allow multiple In-process virtual apps within the same app service plan.
- I have resolved the issue by changing `AspNetCoreModuleV2` to `AspNetCoreModule`
- Edit all the `Web.config` files under the deployed Applications.

[image]

***Output :***

[image]

Comment: Wow! What a comprehensive answer.. Thank you so much Harshitha. I have seen bits and pieces but nobody has put it together quite like you did. I have yet to work through this, but this obviously is the answer! I will check back and confirm that I was able to duplicate the results!

Comment: This was awesome. I have been scratching my head for more time than I care to admit. This is the first article I've come across that walks through the entire process. One thing to add for .net core 7 apps is that there is no web.config locally (that I found) you'll need to go into the app service and go to app service editor on the left side. From there you'll see them if you expand each apps folder.

Comment: @StephanYoung Glad that it helped you.Yes,In .NET Core Applications,`Web.config` file is not available initially.Once we deploy the App we can find it in the `wwwroot` directory in KUDU Console.

Comment: @Harshitha so let me ask you this. I have everything configured and it shows the front page correctly. However it's not appending the virtual folder to the url after I login through my apps. I've been trying, and failing, through Front Door to setup a rewrite rule with no success. Do you have any info on how I can append the virtual folder to the url? So if it's dev.mydomain.com/abc I need abc to stay there.