# How to route requests between ports based on sub-domains?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice

I am using Azure App Service and looking for a way to achieve my goal like the picture attached below. **One single app service** with multiple sites, each site listening on a different port, and then routing clients' requests to a particular port based on domain name.
[image]

The first idea came into my mind was `IIS` or `Nignx`, but haven't found out how to install and configure that in the app service.

I am not sure if this architecture is possible or not by using the Azure app service, based on what I've searched is that it is possible to do a path mapping using `virtual applications & directories` feature.

```
https://corey.com/miracles
https://corey.com/scientist
https://corey.com/yellow
```

That solution also works for me but it affects SEO settings so it's not the perfect one.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, you won't be able to change the port because only 80 and 443 are open in Azure App Services. You can definitely have multiple domains to the same App Service but the configuration which website you will serve will be on your application

Comment: What does your mean  by SEO settings ?

Comment: @Harshitha I read some articles that mentioned subdomain is better than subdirectory for SEO settings.

Comment: @ViniciusDeschamps I do expect all requests to come through the 80 and 443 ports.

Comment: @ViniciusDeschamps "which website you will serve will be on your application" -> would you mind explaining more?

Comment: @Corey you can configure multiple custom domains on your App Service, and you will point the DNS to the same App Service. Then on your application, you have the ability (at least in .NET, using web.config) to add certain parameters to tell something like "hitting miracles.corey.com goes to this folder in the application". A good example of what I am saying is here but it is for Wordpress https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/how-to-set-up-subdirectory-multisite-in-wordpress-on-azure-app/ba-p/3791071

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Vinicius Deschamps for the comments.

- Virtual Application is one of the best options for Azure App Services hosted on Windows Environment.

Refer this [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74948250/19648279) which I have answered to work with Virtual Applications.

- AFAIK,you cannot directly install the `IIS` or `Nginx` in the Azure App Service.

> ASE are accessible only from virtual machines (VMs)

- [Nginx.com](https://www.nginx.com/blog/securing-applications-microsoft-azure-app-service-nginx-plus/#Understanding-Azure-App-Service-Environments:%7E:text=Using%20NGINX%C2%A0Plus%20with%20Azure%20App%20Service%20to%20Secure%20Applications) explains how to use Nginx for an Azure App Service.
- Another option available is to use the [Application Gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/multiple-site-overview).
- Application gateway acts like a load balancer and enables you to manage your applications.

[image]